# DirectoryServices PrincipalContext can add to first level container but not to child container

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices

Not sure what I am missing here.   I've tried using DirectoryEntry and PrincipalContext and have the same problem both ways.   The AD is structured like

```
root (okwu.edu)
    students
        AGS
        Traditional
```

I can add users to the student container with

```
PrincipalContext domainContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "OKWU.EDU", "OU=Students,DC=okwu,DC=edu", systemAccount, systemAccountPassword);

UserPrincipal user = new UserPrincipal(domainContext, model.SamAccountName, model.Password, true);
```

but if I use the dn for AGS (or traditional)

```
 PrincipalContext domainContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "OKWU.EDU", "OU=AGS,OU=Students,DC=OKWU,DC=edu", systemAccount, systemAccountPassword);
```

Then I get an error that the object doesn't exist on the server.   I have found stuff for the first level container but nothing to explain what I am missing when I try to go to the second level container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of three different possiblities.

**Possibility 1:**

Are you sure the DN is really `OU=AGS,OU=Students,DC=OKWU,DC=edu`?

OU may contain container.  So, it's possible that your DN actually looks like this

```
CN=AGS,OU=Students,DC=OKWU,DC=edu
```

Get ADexplorer or ADSIedit.  Check out their distinguishName first.

**Possibility 2:**

You have multiple domain controllers. One of the domain controller got `OU=AGS,OU=Students,DC=OKWU,DC=edu` created but not the others.  This can be due to the incorrect setup of replication

**Possibility 3:**

Your *SystemAccount* doesn't have permissions to see `OU=AGS,OU=Students,DC=OKWU,DC=edu`.  To prove that, you can try login as *SystemAccount* when using ADSIedit.

Comment: I've copied the dn from adsiedit.   I'll try it with CN=username appended on to the DN and try it.

Comment: Another possible reason is you have multiple domain controllers.  One domain controller got the ou but not the other one

Comment: One more possible reason is your system account does not have enough permissions to see your child OU.  Login using your system account when you are using ADSIEDIT

Comment: ahh good point.  I will try that also.  it is the same account I used to read from the child OU but its worth a shot.

Comment: you hit it the closest.   messing around with trying to start the directoryentry from the first level container and I could save to traditional ok but not AGS digging in to it saw that students was spelled wrong and i was testing against AGS so that's why it couldn't find the container.   I hate it when that happens.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly because you don't change your principal context to "OU=AGS,OU=Students,DC=okwu,DC=edu" :

```
PrincipalContext domainContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "OKWU.EDU", "OU=AGS,OU=Students,DC=okwu,DC=edu", systemAccount, systemAccountPassword);
```

Comment: that's when I get the object doesn't exist error.   I've gone in to ADSIEdit and copied the dn from the container.   using the OU=AGS,OU=STudents,DC=OKWU,DC=EDU I can read the records from AD, but trying to create a new entry is when it fails.

Comment: Do you really call `user.Save();`